# Python merging two array type dataframes to one

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovYvJ.png)I have two dataframes as below images

Dataframe 1

```
0                                 [1, 50]
2                               [7, 8, 9]
5    [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
1        [60, 61, 62, 63, 66, 64, 65, 67]
3                        [80, 81, 72, 83]
4                            [90, 91, 92]
6                              [200, 201]
7                              [301, 300]
```

Dataframe 2

```
0                         [1, 2]
1                         [3, 4]
2                         [5, 6]
3    [7, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76]
4                   [10, 11, 12]
6                       [30, 31]
7                       [40, 41]
5                [100, 100, 102]
```

What is the best way or how can I obtain a dataframe or a list like this

```
[1, 50, 2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
[7,8,9,71,72,73,74,75,76,80,81,83]
[10,11,12]
[20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
.......
....
"
```

Basically, I want to merge the arrays if they contain either one element on an array/list on the other dataframe. I have two dataframes which contains million records, so I need an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function `add_dataframes(d1, d2)`

The code would look similar to:

```
add_dataframes(d1, d2):
    d3 = d1 + d2
    //Check for duplicates here (I can do this later if you want, don't have time right now)
   return d3
```

Then with that just iterate through all your lines and create new ones like:

```
dataframe = add_dataframes(//first data , //second data)
```

Comment: I did a similar approach but to check whether a value is inside an array i will have to iterate through one whole dataframe each time, so it consumes a huge time